# Very high NQPD values for very short lines (sDNA)

Tags: network-analysis, sdna

I noticed that whenever a network has very short lines (less than 1-2 m), the NQPD value calculated by sDNA tends to be very high. Very short lines are often network errors, but this effect can also be observed in round-abouts or short connectors between parallel streets.
I tried to figure out why that happens, but did not conclude on the reason. In a recent calculation on a country-wide network, I got values over 300 and 400 (r=50 km, link-weighted, Euclidean-Angular routing) on links less than 1 m in length (and likely network errors).

As a remedy, I either remove (merge, etc.) all short lines and simplify round-abouts, which is not feasible in large networks. Alternatively, I set short (<2m) links with extremely high NQPDs to "NA". That is arbitrary.
Alternatively, I just divide reach (link-weighted) by MED, which is similar but still a different measure. Are there more elegant ways to mitigate this issue?
I attached an example. The short link is just 0.7 m long. The NQPDEn value is 4.8. The connected link to the NW has a value of 0.085.

I also wonder if an NQPD over 1 is even logical - the (weighted) link count would in that case exceed the distance to all links.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess with very short links in the network like this, perhaps the assumptions underpinning link weighting (e.g. that they are a proxy for origins/destinations) maybe starts to break down. It will be the link's interation with itself (mean distance from any part of a 1m link to itself = 0.33m) and its very close neighbours that cause it to be an outlier.

NQPD>1 does make sense, as link weighted NQPD is a sum of (1/distance). So any destination link with distance<1 will add >1 to the total NQPD score for the origin.

One approach may be to switch to length weighting - then anything very short will also be down-rated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I will try length-weighted and see how that affects results. However, since I see a strong correlation between measures weighted by links and measures weighted by population or floor area, I would rather keep using link weighted. For all aggregate measures I will simply set the unreasonable high NQPDs to NA. In disaggregate analysis, it is unlikely that a point/link of interest happens to be one of the very short ones anyway. 
Indeed - it is sum of (1/distance). Thank you for clarifying/reminding.